# Does Google Play Game Services ignore score submissions to a leaderboard that are lower than what is already on that leaderboard for that player

Tags: google-play-services

Does Google Play Game Services ignore score submissions to a leaderboard that are lower than what is already on that leaderboard for that player, for instance when a player restarts a character or reinstalls the game.

The documentation doesn't address this from what I can see. In experimenting with this the service appears to ignore lower scores like it should, but I'd like to be sure so there could be less code management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards) ("Understanding leaderboards" section):

> At the end of a game (or at an appropriate moment that you've determined), the game submits
> the player's score to one or more leaderboards you've created for the game.
>
> The Games services checks if this score is better than the player's
> current leaderboard entry for the daily, weekly, or all-time score. If
> it is, the Games services updates the corresponding leaderboards with
> the new score.

Also, when a user uninstalls a game it does **not** remove any leaderboard scores or achievements - the user needs to explicitly remove these by unlinking the app. In other words, the leaderboard scores will remain even if the app is uninstalled and then re-installed at a later stage.

Comment: Huh, so does this mean that every player can only have one score on the leaderboard? If John Doe played a game in 3 different occasions and he achieved so high score that all of them beats everyone else, he won't take the first 3 places in the top leaderboard? IN case of a real world pinball machine, a user can occupy several entries in the leaderboard. That's what I'd expect from GPGS leaderboards too.

Comment: What you are referring to is a high score table. A leaderboard is a single entry ranking system where each player can only ever have one rank to match the highest score they've achieved. If you want the scores themselves to be recorded (with a name attached) then you will have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Until now I thought the two are the same. I wish Game API would have highscore table too then. I'm little sad.